# How to manage objects' initialization data?

Tags: c++, memory

I have dilema and would be glad to hear from someone who is more experienced in c++.
To be exact my dilema is how to manage (create) initialization data for objects. For example I have several objects, each needs it's own unique set of data used to initialize this object. Each object is initialized on the beginning of application and it's initialization data is not needed afterwards. I have two ideas of how it can be done and i would like to seek advice in terms which one is better (in terms of compiled executable size and optionally runtime memory usage).

Idea 1 (example):

```
struct A
{
  static int data1;
  static float data2;
  static char data3;
};

int A::data1 = 1;
float A:data2 = 1.5;
char A::data3 = 'c';

int main()
{
  *do something with this data*
}
```

Idea 2 (example):

```
struct A
{
  int data1;
  float data2;
  char data3;

  A()
  {
    data1 = 1;
    data2 = 1.5;
    data3 = 'c';
  }

};

int main()
{
  A a;

  *do something with this data*
}
```

There will be several different objects to initialize and each type of object can be created more than once so in first example i would need to create multiple structs with unique data for multiple objects with the same type and in second example i could pass to constructor `A::A()` index and in constructor with `switch` choose which set of data to assign.

Comment: One thing that might be useful is that constructors can receive arguments. In my opinion, complexity wise, the best approach would be to have a constructor with arguments, e.g., `A(int d1, float d2, char d3) : data1{d1}, data2{d2}, data3{d3} {}`

Comment: You could also take advantage of [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). For a simple class it's often better than a constructor because if anything goes wrong it wasn't your fault. Eg: `A a{1, 1.5, 'c'};`

Comment: You also may find the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) useful for managing which initialization values to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple option:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>

struct A
{
  int data1;
  float data2;
  char data3;
};

A factory(int option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case 0:
            return {1, 1.5, 'c'};
        case 1:
            return {2, 3, 'f'};
        case 2:
            return {42, 3.14, 'p'};
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("bad option!");
    }
}

int main()
{
  A a = factory(get_init_option());  
  *do something with this data*
}
```